# How to reverse only the lines that contain a matching?

Tags: bash, shell

like this:

input:

```
Daniel: some_text
Jack: some_text1
Mark: some_text2
Daniel: some_text3
Jack: some_text4
```

output:

```
Daniel: some_text3
Jack: some_text4
Mark: some_text2
Daniel: some_text
Jack: some_text1
```

the mach needs to be the first string before ":"

Comment: What is there are 3 instances of `Daniel`?

Comment: I am not clear on what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: it can be n instances of Daniel .. the 1st is gonna change with the nth one, the second with (n-1)th, the thirs with (n-2)th and so on

Comment: Do this in `awk`, and read the file twice. The first time, create an array whose keys are the names, and the values are the text lines. The second time, look up the name in the array, print the last line in the value, and remove that line from the value.

Comment: I don't understand why this was put into hold. There are two answers of which neither seem simple. Seems like a nice exercise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementation of @Barmar comment but without awk using files to keep arrays of values

```
#!/bin/bash
lines=`cat $1 | tr -d " "`
for line in $lines; do
  key=$(echo $line | cut -d : -f 1)
  value=$(echo $line | cut -d : -f 2)
  echo "$key: $value" >> "$key.tmp";
done

echo -n "" > output.txt
for line in $lines; do
  key=$(echo $line | cut -d : -f 1)
  tail -n 1 $key.tmp >> output.txt
  head -n -1 $key.tmp > temp.tmp
  mv temp.tmp $key.tmp
done

rm *.tmp
```

I used tail and head to simulate the pop function of a stack. Not very performant but it works, has been long time since I don't code in bash

Run the bash script passing a filename as parameter for the input

Comment: `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1][++c[$1]]=$2;next}{print $1, a[$1][c[$1]--]}' file file` Gnu awk solution was a bit tighter.

Answer (score 0):

here is another alternative

```
$ cat -n file > filen; paste <(sort -k2,2 filen) <(sort -k2,2 -k1,1nr filen) | 
  awk '{print $1,$2,$NF}' | 
  sort -n | 
  cut -d' ' -f2-

Daniel: some_text3
Jack: some_text4
Mark: some_text2
Daniel: some_text
Jack: some_text1
```